# Not able to select opacity in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to override my CSS hover actions on a list of links when the container div, in this case #header, has an opacity of 0.5. I'm having a difficult time.

Here's my jQuery:

```
  jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
    if(jQuery(window).scrollTop() > 200) {
        jQuery("#header").css('opacity', '0.5');
    } else {
        jQuery("#header").css('opacity','1');
    }
  });

  if(jQuery("#header").css("opacity") != 1){
      jQuery("#nav li a").hover(function(){
        jQuery(this).css("color","rgba(63, 131, 202, 1)");
      });
  }
```

And here's my CSS:

```
#nav li a {
    color:rgba(63, 131, 202, 1);
    transition: color 1s;
    -webkit-transition: color 1s;
    -o-transition: color 1s;
    -moz-transition: color 1s;
}

#nav li a:hover {
    color:rgba(63, 131, 202, 0.7);
    transition: color 1s;
    -webkit-transition: color 1s;
    -o-transition: color 1s;
    -moz-transition: color 1s;
}
```

I've also tried overriding each transition with none in jQuery, but it's not working. How could I do this? Should I try when the opacity isn't 1, overriding all the none-hover attributes, then overriding the hover attributes like I did above? Not sure what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest keeping as much of your styles in the CSS and simply modify a `class` on the elements that need to change (or on an element higher in the hierarchy, like `body`, if it's going to change several elements). Here's an example:

**Javascript:**

```
jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
    jQuery(document.body).toggleClass("scrolledDown", jQuery(window).scrollTop() > 200)
});
```

**CSS**

```
#nav li a {
    color:rgba(63, 131, 202, 1);
    transition: color 1s;
    -webkit-transition: color 1s;
    -o-transition: color 1s;
    -moz-transition: color 1s;
}

#nav li a:hover {
    color:rgba(63, 131, 202, 0.7);
    transition: color 1s;
    -webkit-transition: color 1s;
    -o-transition: color 1s;
    -moz-transition: color 1s;
}

#header {
    opacity: 1;
}

body.scrolledDown #header {
    opacity: 0.5;
}

body.scrolledDown #nav li a:hover {
    color: rgba(63, 131, 202, 1);
}
```

This will automatically manage your state and keeps your style and javascript separate, which is always nice. You don't have to add the `class` to the `body` element, but I did it here for the sake of a simple example and lack of knowledge of the rest of your DOM structure.

Comment: Great answer. Thanks! The one thing I wonder is the best way to add scrolledDown to my #header div.

Comment: It depends. As you see, the nav's link hover requires that scrolledDown class to be in its hierarchy in order to affect it. If your `#nav` is a child (doesn't matter how deep) of your `#header` you can certainly add it to the `#header` div. Otherwise, you need to find a common ancestor. I picked `body` because I knew it would be a common ancestor regardless of your DOM. :)

Comment: Figured it out. I asked how to add it to my #header div because my attempts weren't working, but I forgot to add a semicolon. I'm serious. :)

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround you could well have more success with:

```
jQuery("#header").fadeTo(0, 0.5);
```

instead of:

```
jQuery("#header").css('opacity', '0.5');
```

Comment: fadeTo has some really weird issues. Scroll up and down here and you'll see what I mean: http://tommaxwell.co/

Answer (score 1):

Stepping through your code in a debugger is useful in cases like this. In this particular scenario, you'd find out that jQuery.fn.css() returns a string even if you're querying a numeric css property, so you'll want to parseFloat() the result.

```
if(parseFloat(jQuery("#header").css("opacity")) != 1)
```

That being said, I'd strongly recommend abandoning querying against style properties altogether and using classes to manage your state instead. Presentation is not information! As a bonus, your link hovers could just be css-based overrides based on the class name rather than being javascript-powered hovers.

Comment: Oh, really? I sorta thought that it would return a string, but got this idea from another SO thread.

Comment: Me in Chrome inspector just now: $('body').css('opacity')
  > "1"

Comment: I'll have to start using that more often.